# Automated scrolling (DOM manipulated) different from mouse scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I'm writing automation test to see whether a sticky bar appears at the bottom of the screen when the page is scrolled to at least a quarter of its height. Through PhantomJS I executed the following line `((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("scrollBy(0, " + oneQuarterOfPage + 1 + ");");`
and upon running the page did scroll by a 1/4 of its height, but the bottom bar did not appear. However, when I instead scrolled with my mouse the bar does appear after having scrolled the necessary amount.

Is there a difference between DOM-manipulated scrolling and mouse-driven scrolling?

The following function is used to detect scrolling and resizing events:

```
$(window).on('scroll DOMMouseScroll resize', function() {
                showBar();
            });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your scrollBy function, but typically in PhantomJS you would use either

```
window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight/4;
```

or

```
page.scrollPosition = {
    top: 100,
    left: 0
};
```

Hope that helps you.